# Why my entry permit to UAE is taking so much time to issue?

Tags: visa, working-visas, passports, uae

It's been 6 working days that my visa is under process in Directorate of Residency and Foreign Affairs, Abu Dhabi, UAE.

I have heard that normally it takes 2-3 working days but mine has 6. My PRO says that it's still under process.

Also, the status of my ELECTRONIC WORK PERMIT APPLICATION is set to USED on the ministry of labour website.

My question is that why it is taking so long. I am a computer engineer from Pakistan waiting for an entry permit to UAE.

Comment: I worked for a very high-up government agency, and sadly, it was often the PRO's fault for delays (laziness).  Follow-up multiple times a day with them and your supervisor and your HR.

Answer (score 1):

Normally it takes at maximum one week for the Entry Permit Visa when all the required documents are submitted in the Ministry. The delay could be for some other reason or if any document got missed and it had to go for the second time.